# Cardano sync stuck with errors: ErrorPolicy and DnsSubscription

Tags: node, error, syncing

Greeting!

My cardano-node sync stuck at 99.65% then getting those errors:
[image]

Cardano-node version - 1.35
Cardano-cli version - 1.35

Any suggestions how to fix those errors?

P.S. A few weeks ago sync was 100%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few days cardano node fully synced. Maybe problem was due to new Babbage era.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the log is from 1.34.0 - Are you sure you restarted the node after upgrading to 1.35.0?
If yes, maybe specify the full path to the process (for example, `/home/<user>/.cabal/bin/cardano-node` instead of just `cardano-node` in your startup command - in case you've got multiple node binaries in your `$PATH` environment variable).

Comment: I initially used 1.35. Cardano-node located only at /var/cardano. My system start up it like service.

Comment: I tried to remove the database folder but the cardano-node still throw errors after 95% sync.